# SUM (IF(COUNTIF)) in excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2013

```
SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)<>1,0,COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)),O1)
```

I would like to display those with same value with same number, however currently only the first value returns a 1, the rest are all 0.
Example:

```
Head 1
Head 1
Head 1
Body 2
Body 2
```

Above is what I want.
But instead I got this:

```
Head 1
Head 0
Head 0
Body 1
Body 0
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

For the non sorted column A use this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)>1,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,A:A,0)),MAX($B$1:$B1)+1)
```

I assumed you will have titles in row 1.  So in B2 put the formula and copy down.

[image]

To make @ForwardEd happy:

[image]

Comment: Show some unsorted data for an unsorted solution 8)

Comment: If we're assuming a header row, I'm not sure whether the extra `COUNTIF` function is helpful. Seems like `=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,A$1:A1,0)),MAX(B$1:B1)+1)` should do the trick just fine. I would expect this to be more efficient on large spreadsheets but I could be wrong. Well I guess it might also depend on the ratio of unique names to total rows.

Answer (score 1):

This method only works if the data of names is sorted or grouped.  If it is not, take a look at Scott Craner's solution for dealing with the unsorted and sorted.

---

Assuming the names are in column A.

place 1 in B1

in B2 place:

```
=B1+IF(A2=A1,0,1)
```

or

```
=B1+(A1<>A2)
```

copy B2 down as far as you need

Comment: FWIW this assumes that the names are sorted in order.  But this was very well done.  I was going the other way to deal when it is not sorted, but I believe this answers the question perfectly.

Comment: I fell in to the trap that the example data was grouped.

Comment: I would assume it unless the OP says it different, but the formula the OP is trying indicated that it might not be.  I say wait and see.

Comment: I'll let you handle to the sorting case 8)